# Keeping strok tokens after the initialization function ends in C

Tags: c, instance-variables, strtok

I have a function foo() that uses strtok() to tokenize a string and sends the tokens to fee(char *new_word) where I need to assign it to a new node. Now that's all well and good, but when foo() and fee() end I need to run bar() that prints the linked list, and from what I can tell the data in the node pointers gets corrupted and I can't use it. How can I hold onto the tokens?

```
struct node{
 char *word;
 struct node *next;
};

struct node top = NULL;

void foo(){
 char *str = "Some words go here";
 char *token = NULL;
 token = strtok(str, "\n");
 while (token){
    fee(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
 }
}

void fee(char * new_word){
 struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 new_node->word = new_word;
 new_node->next = head;
 head = new_node;
}

bar(){
  while (top){
     printf("%s\n", top->word);
     top = top->next;
  }
}
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
foo();
bar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably you need a copy of the token. Show us your actual code. Provide [mcve].

Comment: **Complete and verifiable** also includes that your example must be valid code, that actually compiles. Please copy your real code into the question and don't rewrite something loosely similar from your memory. `struct node top = NULL;` should give you some error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tokens point to memory locations inside the memory block of your original string. When the original string is freed, the tokens will point to garbage. If you want to hold onto the tokens, you must either not free the original string or create a copy of each token (i.e. use `strcpy` or `strdup` - see comment below).

The line that is causing you issues is `new_node->word = new_word;` in `fee()`. Instead assigning the token pointer, you need to allocate memory for `new_node->word` and copy `new_word` into it. When `foo` is done executing, the string memory block is released. By the time `bar` executes, your tokens are pointing to unallocated memory.

Alternatively, if you initialize `char *str = "Some words go here";` in the `main` above `foo()`, and then pass `str` (i.e. `foo(str)`), that will also work since `str` will remain in scope. Just don't try to free `new_node->word` if you go this route, your program will crash.

Comment: Or strdup.  Instead of saying `token=strtok(...); fee(token);` it could be changed to `token=strtok(...); fee(strdup(token));`